# SQL Server and msbi relation and difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, ssrs, ssas

With SQL Server 2008R2, we have analysis services, reporting services, and data moving and manipulation services with SQL Server Management Studio. So why do we need SSIS, SSRS, and SSAS?

Answer (score 3):

The components you mentioned are useful for automating integration, reporting, and analysis services into a complete solution that can be used by non-technical persons.

SQL Server Management Studio is designed for use by technical staff such as developers and system administrators, etc.

Microsoft Business Intelligence (presumably that is what you mean by MSBI in your title), more commonly know as PowerBI, is a solution that extends the services above with connectivity to a wide variety of other data sources in a visually rich way, offering what is touted as an intuitive interface.